# Plot distribution inside a region

Tags: matlab

I have a distribution of points inside a circle.
So, I draw a circular grid inside that circle. I want to find the number of points inside each cell of the circular gird. 
Is there a way to implement that easily. or maybe drawing a grid is not necessary?
My goal is plotting the distribution.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Transform your points to polar coordinates and then it should be pretty simple. I think the function is `cart2pol`

Answer (score 2):

If `X,Y` are the coordinates of the points in your circle, the distances from the center can be obtained with

**(edit: T/H @horchler)**

```
d = sqrt(sum([X(:)-X0 Y(:)-Y0].^2,2));
```

where `X0, Y0` are the coordinates of the center of the circle.

You can then compute a radial distribution using `hist`:

```
figure, hist(d)
```

or if you just want the distribution and bins

```
[distr bins] = hist(d);
```

Comment: I wouldn't employ a `repmat`. Just `d = sqrt(sum([X(:)-X0 Y(:)-Y0]).^2,2));`.

Comment: @horchler, absolutely true!!

Comment: Lets say I have 20000 points and they are in the circled region. The possibility of finding a few points in the exact same spot of the space is not high. Moreover, it will not give me the density distribution of points. So I want to divide the circle into small parts, then calculate the number of points in each part and plot the distribution. Finding the distance from the center will not show the density of distribution I need.

Comment: Ok, it was unclear to me what you intended. I think something like Luis Mendo's solution might work. However a Cartesian grid is the easiest way to partition the area into cells of equal area, which is presumably important.

Comment: I will amend my answer a little later.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes. the problem is more complicated in the case of a circular grid, because each sector has a different area, so another problem concerning calculation of the areas of these small parts arises. Probably it is better to solve this in the case of a rectangular grid.

Answer (score 1):

By "circular Grid" I understand a grid in azimuth and modulus. I suggest you convert to polar coordinates:

```
z = x + j*y; % x, y are vectors woth x, y coordinates of the points
az = angle(z); % note that this gives azimuth in radians
mod = abs(z);
```

and then apply some kind ot 2D histogram to `az` and `mod`, for example using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9896-2d-histogram-calculation) function. (Please note it is a user-contributed file. I haven't tested it myself).